# multilingual database schema for mvc dot.net model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, multilingual

We had developed in the past some sites, from company presentation sites to eshops, in classic asp. All of these was developed in multilingual environment (el, en) most of them. From database view we had choose the following schema. For example, for products table we have two related tables one with no lingual depended fields and one for lingual depended fields with one to many relation.

```html
CREATE TABLE ref_language (
  Code Char(2)NOT NULL,
  Name Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Code)
);
 
CREATE TABLE app_product (
 Id Int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
 
CREATE TABLE app_product_translation (
 ProductId Int NOT NULL,
 LanguageCode Char(2) NOT NULL,
 Description Text NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES app_product(Id),
 FOREIGN KEY (LanguageCode) REFERENCES ref_language(Code)
);
```

To recreate the product model we use stored procedures to join the two tables for the requested language.
Now we want to move into dot.net mvc model. And we are wondering if there is a better approach, most suitable in mvc  model.

Comment: In your schema a product can have many descriptions. I would suggest having a general app_translation table with Id, LanguageCode, Translation fields, unique index on ResourceId and LanguageCode, Then have a field in app_project called ResourceId. Then you can only have one caption per language per product. And you can reuse the translations table across your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirements, but you can just create a class to load and cache the captions in memory, loading them using EF. Either use a static class or preferably the ASP.NET cache.

If you are doing dynamic stuff on the client side then expose the strings through a MVC of WebAPI controller if necessary.

To make this easier I would decouple your translations from products in the schema. Make your translations universal.

Just have a single table called app_translation with Id, LanguageCode and Translation field. Then reference the Id on any table that needs a translated caption.

To enforce referential integrity, you can also have a app_translation_identifier table with a single column and a unique constraint. Then FK from the app_translation.Id to app_tranlsation_identifier.Id. And also have a unique key on app_translation for the Id and LanguageCode.

Comment: The problem is not only the field captions, for annotations etc. Let me give you an example. We have a table (prd) in which we store products. We want the site administrator to be able to insert new records and give multilingual descriptions.
Insert into prd (prd_id, prd_description) select (3, ‘mushrooms’)
Right now we have a second table in which we store the prd_id to join it with the first and the user can add as many descriptions as there are languages.
Insert into prd_lang (prd_id, lang_id, prd_description) select (3, ‘fr’, ‘champignons’)

Comment: Users adding descriptions in many languages can also be done in a generic way with just a single table called user_translation. What is the problem that is blocking you from making progress? I don't think there is a baked-in solution for this in MVC you will need to roll your own. By running everything off 1 or 2 tables, you can have a controller or class that gets you any caption you like for any table. This has to be the simplest way.

Comment: Thank you Martin this makes more clear for me the use of translation tables.